# Is there a shell-script (using Ubuntu) lib for edit mp3's album and artist?

Tags: shell, scripting, mp3

Is there a shell-script (using Ubuntu) lib for edit mp3's album and artist (get and set the strings

**--update**

I've tried all those "id3.." programs, but seems like no one of them let me just read an artist or an album to a variable. They all just let me set it with a string.. I would like to get the value too..

Isn't there a simple way to do such a simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-script-for-sorting-and-renaming-multiple-mp3-files-by-id3-tags-602105/

Especially further down where they recommend eyeD3.

IMHO this was really a question for "let me google that for you".

Comment: I've tried all those "id3.." programs, but seems like no one of them let me just read an artist or an album to a variable. They all just let me set it with a string.. I would like to get the value too..

Comment: By the way, I have googled by shell scripts and none of them worked.. so I asked ;)

Comment: There's some problems with the eyeD3, some files just aren't editable with it.. and the mail list is returning as undelivered. But is the best one I found either. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`id3ed`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/MP3-HOWTO-13.html)

[download the package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/id3ed)

Comment: looks like it can only set the values.. I would like to get the value and add to a variable

Comment: @Tom Brito - the docs saying using `id3ed -i = show current id3 tag only, don't edit`